# Is redundant assignment elimination fairly typical optimization?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Given the following:

```
len = strlen(str);
/* code that does not read from len */
len = new_len;
```

Can I depend on the compiler to remove the first line?

I'm writing a code generating script. The first line is generated in one place, while everything that follows is generated elsewhere (by a virtual function in a descendant class). Most of the time, len isn't needed. Sometimes though, it is. I wonder if I can just set it in all cases and let the compiler get rid of the line if it isn't required.

Comment: It's not a redundant assignment unless the compiler knows the function has no side-effects, the variable is local, etc.

Answer (score 4):

No, of course you cannot "depend" on the optimization choices done by the compiler.

They can change at the user's whim (compiler command line options), or with different compiler versions.

Since the behavior you're describing is not required by the language standard, you cannot depend on compilers to implement it.

On the other hand, you can surely test it, and try to "coax" it into being optimized out, by (again) asking your compiler to do as much optimization as possible, for instance.

Comment: I second that. Also, the code sample depends on the the function call (strlen) to be side effect free *and* the compiler knowing about it. Contemporary gcc understands this aspect about strlen, but you can't depend on that behaviour for arbitrary functions on different compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are pretty clever. But to rely on the compiler removing "unused" function calls is probably not a good idea. For one thing, the compiler will NEED to understand the function you are calling (so strlen is a good example here, because most compilers understand what strlen does and how it affects other things) - if the function is not one that the compiler "understands", then it can't optimise it out.

What if you did:

```
 x = printf("Hello, World!\n");

 x = printf("World, Hello!\n");
```

Would you think they compiler had done the right thing by removing the first printf? Probably not... So, with any function the compiler can't determine "is side-effect free", the compiler MUST call the function, even if the result is not used. Side-effect free means under normal circumstances - e.g. there is a side-effect of calling strlen() with an invalid pointer - your code will probably crash - but that's not "normal circumstances" - you'd be pretty daft to use strlen() just to check if your pointer is a valid one or not, right?

So, in other words, you probably want to make sure your call to strlen() is really needed before you call strlen - or live with the fact that the compiler may wall generate an unnecessary strlen call.

Comment: Can we not get all academic here? I understand the issue well enough. I just didn't know whether compilers commonly do it in practice.

Comment: Yes, the compiler MAY optimise it way, but ONLY for functions that the compiler knows are "free of side-effects", which I think is what my answer says. And compilers are not reliable in that either, meaning that if you make your code complex enough the compiler may well "give up" on trying to remove redundant functions - they typically use recursive functions with limits on how deep the functions go before "giving up".

Comment: @cleong: Well, neither do we have to answer at all, nor do you have to vote it up or accept it. I am not sure how much you are in a position to demand things from us unpaid volunteers.

Comment: I should perhaps clarify: Without knowing what compiler(s) you are intending to use, and what the code looks like, it is impossible to say yes or no. If, say, you plan on using the 15-20 year old Borland C++ compiler, the answer is different from a gcc/Microsoft/Intel compiler of the modern age. And I have no idea what Sun or IBM's compilers do. I'm sure they also have some clever compiler staff, so they do a decent job [and the guys working at Borland were/are good too - it's just that computers and compilers have moved on since, so using 1GB of ram is not longer "impossible"]

Comment: @phresnel Well, I was hoping it's something someone has looked into. This kind of scenarios happens all the time when you writes macros, where you can feel free to leave in redundant code knowing the compiler will optimize it out. I don't know what induces people to bring up C standard and stuff.

Comment: So, you'd be much happier if I just said "Yes", and then later you find out that it isn't true? I can always edit my answer to suit what you want it to say, if you tell me... ;) But I'm trying to give you the answer that I know is CORRECT, not what you want to hear - that's what politicians do, and I'm probably quite a long way from being a politician (or a diplomat). Unfortunately, by being honest and correct, I'm not able to give you an answer that is 100% "yes" or "no", but "it depends on the circumstances". Which of course begs the question, have you tried to run the compiler and see?

Comment: @cleong: If they bring up C standard and stuff, which they can only do due to their experience, and experience is time, and time is money, so that's something that has some worth, you can just ignore their answer. Mats answer wasn't incorrect or unrelated, it even gives some insight that teaches you fishing instead of just giving you the fish. My feeling is that instead of being thankful or just ignoring his answer, you were rantful. You know, if you want someone to rant on or give commands to, why not go to a paid support site?

Answer (score 1):

Modern compilers do seem to do an excellent job of eliminating redundant assignments. I ran the following snippet through VS 2008 and gcc 4.6 and the call to strlen (the inlined code, rather) is in fact removed. Both compilers managed to see that the both `something()` and `something_else()` produce no side effects. Calls to these are removed as well.

This occurs at /O1 in VC and /O1 in gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int something(int len)  {
    if(len != len) {
        printf("%d\n", len);
    }
    return 0;
}

int something_else(int len) {
    return len * len;
}

int main(void) {
    char *s = malloc(1000);
    size_t len;
    strcpy(s, "Hello world");
    len = strlen(s);
    something(len);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    len += 8;
    something_else(len);
    len = 5;
    printf("%d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on compiler & the optimization level you specify.

Here it gets assigned initially from a function call. What if that function has a side effect?

So you cannot just assume the compiler to optimize it for you.

If the initial assignment statement is free from any side effects & you specify optimization level good enough (e.g. -O3 in case of gcc) it may optimize it for you.

Comment: The question was if he could depend on it, though.

Comment: hmm, right... I wanted to mention point of side effect of 1st assignment.